# Cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Action<GoogleMobileAds.Api.InitializationStatus>' in C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

This is Google admob script but Unity gives me the error

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Action<GoogleMobileAds.Api.InitializationStatus>'.
```

It underlines appID in the void Start() function.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using GoogleMobileAds;
using System;

public class addmanager_script : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public BannerView bannerview;
    public InterstitialAd regularad;
    private string appID="ca-app-pub-5133215721502784~7588202759";
    private string regularID="ca-app-pub-5133215721502784/3265814366";
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        MobileAds.Initialize (appID);
        //RequestAd ();
        RequestBanner ();
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {

    }

    public void OnClickShowBanner()
    {
        this.RequestBanner ();
    }

    public void OnClickShowAd()
    {
        this.RequestAd ();
    }

    private void RequestAd()
    {
        regularad = new InterstitialAd (regularID);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder ().Build ();
        regularad.LoadAd (request);
    }

    private void RequestBanner()
    {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        string bannerID = "ca-app-pub-5133215721502784/6909545908";
        #elif UNITY_IPHONE
        string adUnitId = bannerID;
        #else
        string bannerID  ="ca-app-pub-5133215721502784/6909545908";
        #endif

        bannerview = new BannerView (bannerID, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder ().Build ();
        bannerview.LoadAd (request);
        bannerview.Show ();
        //bannerview.OnAdLoaded += HandleOnAdLoaded;

    }

    void HandleOnAdLoaded(object a, EventArgs args)
    {
        print ("loaded");
        bannerview.Show ();
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        if (regularad.IsLoaded ()) 
        {
           regularad.Show ();
         }

    }

}
```

I don't understand what the solution to this is as I am new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/quick-start).

```
...
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
...
public class GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Start()
    {
        // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK.
        MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });
    }
}
```

So the problem is that you don't need to pass any string argument to MobileAds.Initialize, instead you need to pass a delegate/action/callback that receives by parameters a `GoogleMobileAds.Api.InitializationStatus`.

So you can do it like in the example above, or something like:

```
...
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
...
public class GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Start()
    {
        // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK.
        MobileAds.Initialize(OnMobileAdsInitialized);
    }

    private void OnMobileAdsInitialized(InitializationStatus initStatus)
    {
        //Do something with that status
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. But what is supposed to go in the OnMobileInitialized function?